# django.db.utils.IntegrityError when using raw sql queries in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

The entire error is `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '6' for key 'auth_user.PRIMARY'")`

I'm getting this error when using Django to create a sign-up page with raw SQL queries. It comes up when trying to insert values into the 'auth_user' table that is created by Django. The model in question is 'User' from 'django.contrib.auth.models.' and I'm using MySQL as my database management system.

Here is the snippet of my view.py:

```
def admin_signup_view(request):
    form = forms.AdminSigupForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AdminSigupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'auth_user'")
            fields = cursor.fetchall()
            fields_list = [element for tupl in fields for element in tupl]
            values_list=[]
            for key,value in user.__dict__.items():
                if key in fields_list:
                    if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                        value=value.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'")
                    elif isinstance(value, str):
                        value=str("'{}'".format(value))
                    elif value is None:
                        value='NULL'
                    values_list.append(value)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO auth_user VALUES (" + ', '.join(str(v) for v in values_list) + ");")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('adminlogin')
    return render(request, 'hospital/adminsignup.html', {'form': form})
```

The issue is caused by `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO auth_user VALUES (" + ', '.join(str(v) for v in values_list) + ");")` line (i.e 3rd last line). Even though the above error is raised the 'auth_user' table is populated with the data entered in the form (I know because I manually checked the database), the only difference being that the password isn't hashed. I have also tried printing the string in this INSERT command before the cursor.execute() statement and it prints with the hashed password.

Here is a relevant snippet of my forms.py:

```
#for admin signup
class AdminSigupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['first_name','last_name','username','password']
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }
```

I'm new to Django and MySQL. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error seems self explanatory.  You are trying to insert the value '6' for auth_user more than one time which you cannot do since it is designated as a primary key for that table

Comment: @JD2775 I understand but the INSERT command only executes once in the code. Why will it give an error for inserting more than once?

Comment: @ShrishShankar `user = form.save()` already saves the user to the database, you later try to insert it again obviously giving you an error... Not to mention the way you make the query you are **vulnerable to SQL injection**.